# Synchronizing stream outputs

Tags: node.js, express, stream, synchronization, aws-sdk

I am working on uploading different image sizes to the amazon s3 storage. Whenever I upload an image, I create three separate readable streams of the image and pipe it to my resizer functions and the s3 upload function.

Each of the streams uploads different size of an image to the s3 cloud. I would like the synchronize the outputs of the streams so that I can send the URLs of the uploaded photos when the uploading has completed in all of the three streams.

I am not able to know when all my streams have ended. Or how can I wait until all my streams have ended and then return the URLs of all the uploaded images?

Here is my code

resize.js

```
import fs from 'fs';
import sharp from 'sharp';

export const resizeThumbnail = function (path, format) {
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(path);
  let transform = sharp();
  if (format) {
    transform = transform.toFormat(format);
  }
  transform = transform.resize(100);
  return readStream.pipe(transform);
};

export const resizeLowRes = function (path, format) {
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(path);
  let transform = sharp();
  if (format) {
    transform = transform.toFormat(format);
  }
  transform = transform.resize(500);
  return readStream.pipe(transform);
};

export const resizeHighRes = function (path, format) {
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(path);
  let transform = sharp();
  if (format) {
    transform = transform.toFormat(format);
  }
  transform = transform.resize(1080);
  return readStream.pipe(transform);
};
```

resizer.js

```
import { resizeThumbnail, resizeLowRes, resizeHighRes } from './resize';
import awsConfig from '../config/awsConfig';
import { uploadFromStream } from './amazonS3';

// receives a list of images
export const resizer = (images, id, callback) => {
  const imageList = images.split(',');
  const store = [];
  imageList.forEach((imagePath, i) => {
    sizeCreator(imagePath, id, i, (err, localstore) => {
      if (!err) {
        store.push(localstore);
        console.log(store);
      }
      callback(err);
    });
  });
};

const sizeCreator = (imagePath, id, i, callback) => {
  const localstore = {};
  resizeThumbnail(imagePath).pipe(uploadFromStream(awsConfig, id, i, 'thumbnail', (err, data) => {
    localstore.thumbnail = {
      url: data.Location,
      filename: data.key,
    };
  }));
  resizeLowRes(imagePath).pipe(uploadFromStream(awsConfig, id, i, 'lowres', (err, data) => {
    localstore.lowres = {
      url: data.Location,
      filename: data.key,
    };
  }));
  resizeHighRes(imagePath).pipe(uploadFromStream(awsConfig, id, i, 'highres', (err, data) => {
    localstore.highres = {
      url: data.Location,
      filename: data.key,
    };
    callback(err, localstore);
  }));
};
```

amazonS3.js

```
import stream from 'stream';

export const uploadFromStream = (s3, id, index, res, callback) => {
  const pass = new stream.PassThrough();
  const params = {
    Bucket: 'Bucket',
    Key: `${id}_${res}_${index}`,
    Body: pass,
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
  };
  s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
    callback(err, data);
  });
  return pass;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can counting started stream and updating counter on finish stream event. When last stream is finished counter should have value 0. Then you can trigger different event which send the url.

Comment: Thanks, your idea helped. It works now. But is there a better way to handle through async await?